# Aliases created in terminal not showing up in tmux. Why?

Tags: bash, tmux

I create  a few aliases in terminal like below:

```
alias k=kubectl
source <(kubectl completion bash)
```

And then I open a tmux session with command: `tmux`.

Now inside of tmux pane, when I try using the alias and expect the behaviour of source command run in terminal, it fails! :(

Why does this happen and how do I get it right?

The context is that I end up using multiple panes in tmux and I don't want to re-peat the same set of aliases creation again and again as I open every tmux pane. Possible?

Comment: In short, aliases are not inherited by the shell that is started via `tmux`. You would have to instantiate the aliases in the `tmux` pane.

Comment: Have appended the context just so you can answer it as well. Also, it would be great  you write your answer as answer instead of as comment, just so I can mark it as correct answer to aid future readers of this question :)

Comment: The answer is already given, to the duplicate question.

Comment: But that is about aliases in bash. And this question is about exporting bash aliases to tmux environment, so that it is available in every pane in the tmux. I was wondering if I missed any tmux configuration for this.

Comment: You have not missed any `tmux` configuration. Aliases are not exportable (i.e. not part of the environment that is inherited by child processes). `tmux` is just a program that runs other programs, so `tmux` really has nothing to do with this, other than that it starts a new `bash` session for you. Test this: `alias t='echo hi'` then run the command `bash` to start a new shell. The `t` alias is not available in the new shell. Aliases are not inherited.

Comment: Okay point taken. Now you marked this question as duplicate. How on earth will someone undergoing the  same situation like me, understand that this is a duplicate to the question that you pointed out, unless he knows the cause of the  problem. And if he were to have known the cause of the  problem, he probably would figure things out himself. Think about it for a moment. I am afraid you are trying to over-optimize the QnA thingy in StackOverflow. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I'll reopen and I'll post an answer. Who knows, someone may even post a better answer than me.

Comment: another point to notice about tmux is that it will start login shells by default, ie its shells won't source `~/.bashrc` unless that file is sourced from `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @mosvy that is an interesting point. So in case of Ubuntu, how do you think is the call chain constructed? and will creating one of these ~/.bashrc or ~/.bassh_profile file and defining alises in it be of help to see these defined aliases in tmux panes without redefining them again?

Comment: I put my aliases & everything bash-specific in `~/.bashrc`, everything shell-portable in `~/.profile` and have a `~/.bash_profile` which just sources them both. FWIW, ubuntu, debian and derived are special because they will also source `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc` (which is not the default upstream and does not happen on other systems like rhel or centos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmux` is just a program that runs other programs, so `tmux` really has nothing to do with this, other than that it starts a new `bash` session for you. Test this:  Do `alias t='echo hi'` in a terminal, then run the command `bash` to start a new shell (in the same terminal). The new `t` alias is not available in the new shell. Aliases are not inherited. Only environment variables are inherited (and a few other things, like what the current directory is).

In short, aliases are not inherited by the shells that are started via `tmux`. You would have to instantiate the aliases in each `tmux` pane (possibly by adding the alias definitions to you `~/.bashrc` file).